# Always-On VPN profile does not add custom route

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, alwayson

My server is 2012R2. I deployed AOVPN according to [Microsoft manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/always-on-vpn/deploy/always-on-vpn-deploy-deployment) using PowerShell for clients deployment. It all works except **custom route just does not appear on a client** (tried on multiple Windows 10 and Windows 11 PCs) without any hints anywhere. `DisableClassBasedDefaultRoute` works.

I tried to modify recommended `MakeProfile.ps1` with adding VPN connection via MDM_VPNv2_01 WMI class and add VPN connection with classic `Add-VpnConnection` instead with custom route like this `Add-VpnConnectionRoute`. It works, route does appear but the logon script doesn't run when a client is not connected to the network as it's usually is for remote clients. It seems like "incorrect" ProfileXML overrides the route added with `Add-VpnConnection` after few client reboots (I don't fully understand a logic) and custom route disappears, so it works but unreliable.

Please help to find an error in ProfileXML or anywhere else:

```
<VPNProfile>

   <AlwaysOn>true</AlwaysOn>
   <RememberCredentials>true</RememberCredentials>   
   <DnsSuffix>mydomain.local</DnsSuffix>
   <RegisterDNS>true</RegisterDNS>
   <TrustedNetworkDetection>mydomain.local</TrustedNetworkDetection>
   
   <DomainNameInformation>
      <DomainName>.mydomain.local</DomainName>
      <DnsServers>192.168.99.1,192.168.99.100</DnsServers>
   </DomainNameInformation>

   <NativeProfile>
      <Servers>vpn.external.com</Servers>
      <RoutingPolicyType>SplitTunnel</RoutingPolicyType>    
      <NativeProtocolType>IKEv2</NativeProtocolType>
      <DisableClassBasedDefaultRoute>true</DisableClassBasedDefaultRoute>

      <CryptographySuite>
         <AuthenticationTransformConstants>SHA256128</AuthenticationTransformConstants>
         <CipherTransformConstants>AES256</CipherTransformConstants>
         <EncryptionMethod>AES256</EncryptionMethod>
         <IntegrityCheckMethod>SHA256</IntegrityCheckMethod>
         <DHGroup>Group14</DHGroup>
         <PfsGroup>None</PfsGroup>
      </CryptographySuite>
      
     <Authentication>
         <UserMethod>Eap</UserMethod>
         <Eap>
            <Configuration>
               <EapHostConfig xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
                  <EapMethod>
                     <Type xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">26</Type>
                     <VendorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorId>
                     <VendorType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorType>
                     <AuthorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</AuthorId>
                  </EapMethod>
                  <Config xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
                     <Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                        <Type>26</Type>
                        <EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2ConnectionPropertiesV1">
                           <UseWinLogonCredentials>true</UseWinLogonCredentials>
                        </EapType>
                     </Eap>
                  </Config>
               </EapHostConfig>
            </Configuration>
         </Eap>
      </Authentication>  
    </NativeProfile>  

    <Route>
      <Address>192.168.96.0</Address>
      <PrefixSize>20</PrefixSize>
      <Metric>1</Metric>
    </Route>
       
</VPNProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use custom routes myself but I was fighting with how to Disable class based routing. Your example above pointed me in the right direction.

Anyhow: The way I added customs  routes was through PowerShell:

Assuming your VPN connection is called `MyVpn` you could add a custom route with the Cmdlet `Add-VpnConnectionRoute` like so:

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "MyVpn" -DestinationPrefix 192.168.96.0/20 -PassThru
```

The route is associated with you VPN connection, so it will only appear in your routing table while the VPN connection is up.

Answer (score 0):

You should 100% be able to have the routes configured in the XML.
2 things are different with your XML compared to the ones I run that work perfectly:

1. I have `<RememberCredentials>` set to faslse
2. I don't use `<Metric>` in the `<Route>` configuration

Number 2 is likely the culprit here.

Additionally, are you only configuring a User Tunnel? Because if you're also configuring a device tunnel, and something is configured incorrectly in that, it can affect the User Tunnel as well.

e.g. Don't configure `<DomainNameInformation>` in a device tunnel. Or if you *absolutely* have to, make sure all `<DomainNameInformation>` are identical in both profiles.